# Bitcoind JSON comment error

Tags: json, bitcoin

Trying to add a comment (in json) to a transaction but keep getting this error: "error: value is type obj, expected int"

`bitcoind  move acc1 acc2 0.00000002 '{"test":"hi"}'`

Answer (score -1):

I was missing the `minconf=1` arg value (ie. needed a 1):

`bitcoind move acc1 acc2 0.00000002 1 '{"test":"hi"}'`